Another more sophisticated and/or elegant way of saying "Sort/Kind of related/similar"
I'm trying to find a more sophisticated and/or elegant way of saying

"Sort/Kind of related/similar"

To elaborate, I'm trying to say the following in a more sophisticated/elegant manner:

John The Baptist of the New Testament's character/role is "sort/kind of
related/similar" to Elijah the Prophet of the Old Testament.

Would the following be correct?  Are there any better alternatives?

John The Baptist of the New Testament's character is "vaguely similar"
to Elijah the Prophet of the Old Testament.


John The Baptist of the New Testament's character is "remotely similar"
to Elijah the Prophet of the Old Testament.


John The Baptist of the New Testament's role is "vaguely related"
to Elijah the Prophet of the Old Testament.


John The Baptist of the New Testament's role  is "remotely related"
to Elijah the Prophet of the Old Testament.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Akin might be the word you are looking for.
Cambridge Dictionary - Akin

Looking or being almost but not exactly the same

John The Baptist of the New Testament's character/role is somewhat akin to the role of Elijah the Prophet of the Old Testament.

I'm no native speaker, but it's a bit odd to pick a word meaning "similarity >= 0.97" and then degrade it with "somewhat" to mean "kind of similar" (which would correspond to a lesser similarity value in my interpetation)

@sylvainulg - Akin  is a perfectly valid English word and is well suited to the OP's situation - often used for exactly the OP's case. ( I am a native English speaker with a background in literature/academia.) "similarity >= 0.97..." - Such quantitative analysis is not really applicable in questions of style, usage and  the nuance of a particular word.

Three verbs with similar meanings:

The role of John The Baptist of the New Testament echoes/recalls/evokes that of Elijah the Prophet of the Old Testament.

echo (v.)

To repeat details that are similar to, and make you think of,
something else:
The design of the church echoes that of St. Paul's Cathedral.
Cambridge

recall (v.)

To cause you to think of a particular event, situation, or style:
His paintings recall the style of Picasso.
Cambridge

Perhaps slightly weaker is
evoke (v.)

To cause something to be remembered or expressed
Cambridge


First, John's initial physical description in chapter 3 evokes
Elijah.
Kendra Mohn; Masculinities in the
Gospel of Matthew Joseph, John, Peter, and Judas (2024)


If you are writing (even a speech or presentation), I would avoid the informal group genitive: "[John The Baptist of the New Testament]'s role" because it can be (mis)read as  the role of the New Testament. We get away with this construction in speech when we start a sentence, paint ourselves into a corner, and use the group genitive to save us from restarting and rephrasing. But we should always rewrite to avoid something like "The boy I saw on the corner yesterday's father is my professor."

@Lambie - I see your comment about re-writing above... BUT the OP is asking for sophistication/elegance.  Re-writing advice seems in order here!

That possessive is bothersome. Putting the noun character or role at the head of the sentence is better.
The character [or role] of John The Baptist in the New Testament is in a way [or somewhat] related to Elijah the Prophet of the Old Testament.
sort of/kind of=in a way or somewhat.
Reference: My own internalized grammar.

There is actually a theological term for this example. For the later person:

antitype [noun]
(1) a person or thing that is foreshadowed or represented by a type or
symbol, especially a character or event in the New Testament
prefigured in the Old Testament.

[Dictionary.com] (the earlier person being the type)


... John the Baptist came in the spirit and power of Elijah, an antitype of Elijah. [ie John the Baptist came in the spirit and power
of Elijah; he is/was an antitype of Elijah.]


[John W Ritenbaugh; BibleTools]

Edwin, how does antitype differ from antetype?

' ... 'antetype' ... is almost the antithesis of 'antitype' ... an antitype follows after and an antetype precedes something with which it is closely related'. [W Y Stern; Academic OUP] // I didn't confuse the issue further by adding that a conflicting sense of 'antitype' is 'something that represents the opposite of a given thing'.

Parallels

John The Baptist of the New Testament's character parallels that of
Elijah the Prophet of the Old Testament.

Dictionary.com says:
2. having the same direction, course, nature, or tendency; corresponding; similar; analogous:
Canada and the United States have many parallel economic interests.

Congruent

John The Baptist of the New Testament's character is congruent to
Elijah the Prophet's of the Old Testament.

Also Dictionary.com:
1. agreeing; accordant; congruous:
His testimony was perfectly congruent with the content retrieved from the suspect’s phone.

With some grammar around the clumsy "Elijah the Prophet's" possessive.

I think 'not dissimilar' would fit nicely here.

Just spitballing here:



JTB of the NT’s character is to some extent comparable to ETP of the OT.




JTB of the NT’s character resembles, although not quite ETP of the OT.




JTB of the NT’s character shares many, yet not all traits of ETP of the OT.




ETP of the OT’s character is reinvented in in JTB of the NT.



